# Extrude level to other element

Tags: extrude

In the picture I have extruded the left cube. How can I extrude the right cube to exactly the same height as the left cube? I could copy the coordinates of the left one to the right one, but that is far too tedious ...

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enable ***Snap during transform*** option (click the magnet icon) and change the *Snap Element type* to ***Vertex***. Extrude along the desired axis (in my case I press <kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd>) and move the cursor until your extruded element snaps to the other mesh's edge.
[image]